# php, mysql, arrays - if( x == 0 ) { }

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, associative-array

I have the following code

```
while($row = $usafisRSP->fetch_assoc())
{

 $hidden_keys  = array('Applicantid', 'unique_num', 'regs_time' ....);
 $hidden_fields = array_intersect_key($row, array_fill_keys($hidden_keys, NULL));

$hidden_values = array();

foreach ($hidden_fields as $key => $value) {
  // fill the values array using the values from fields array
  $hidden_values[$value] =  "$key = ".base64_decode($value)."
";


if(base64_decode($value)== 0)
{
  $hidden_values[$value] = "";
}

 echo $hidden_values[$value];
```

The question is about "if($hidden_values[$value] == 0)" ... Basically I want to do not display/echo the $hidden_values[$value] if it's value of $value is 0. Sometimes $value is 0 or some words like (23 avenue).

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You dont know how to check the contents of the array for 0 values before echoing?

Comment: What's the problem you're experiencing with your current code? Also, it looks like you're missing a couple of closing braces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you ran into three catches with [PHP type comparisons and equalities](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php):

1. Any string not beginning with a number will always loosely equal 0.  So basically, `if(base64_decode($value)== 0)` will likely always resolve to *true*, even if decoded `$value` is `"Adam"`.

   Return value of base64_decode is a string, so if 0 is the result, it will be *string* 0, not *integer* 0.  This means `if(base64_decode($value) === 0)` wouldn't even work if decoded `$value` is `"0"`.  Another catch is base64_decode may return *false* on errors, again failing this strict equality check.

   A non-empty string (other than `"0"`) will always loosely equal *true*.  So this is the only comparison you really need for your case.

I think this is what you want, replacing the last 5 lines...

```
if(base64_decode($value)) echo $hidden_values[$value];
else $hidden_values[$value] = "";

} // closing your for loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
foreach( $hidden_values as $value ) {
    if( $value !== 0 ) {
        echo $value;
    }
}
```